# sudo through ssh on cron

Tags: ssh, sudo, cron

I have this command which runs properly when executed on terminal:

```
ssh someuser@someserver -t "sudo systemctl start someservice"
```

No password asked for ssh, there is a public key to connect, `someuser` can execute sudo to start `someservice` without password.

I need to insert the above command to crontab. Unfortunately it's not executed; I suspect the problem arises from using `ssh -t` for the pseudo-terminal which is needed by sudo. It seems that the pseudo-terminal cannot be implemented through cron (my assumption, no hard evidence).

To summarize, my goal is to execute the command, without interaction, on a timed interval. Any ideas how to sort this following the existing method?

Working alternatives welcomed.

Comment: Are you sure ssh run from crontab is finding its configuration files and private keys? Is it running as the user it usually runs?

Comment: it could be that cron is not reading your ssh key, you said no password is used, try specifying key with -i option in ssh. also you could maybe put the command in script on remote server and just run that script over ssh

Comment: yeah, since all you're doing is start some systemd service, wouldn't it make more sense to have a systemd.timer unit doing that on that server?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's a bit complicated. A file is copied on server1, where there is access. The cron job checks if the file is there, and if found it copies it to someserver, where the ordinary users do not have access. Next step, restarts the service. That's why I cannot use systemd.timer on the destination.

Comment: `sudo systemctl start someservice` does **not** restart a service – it only starts it if it's not already running!

Comment: @MarcusMüller For sure. I mentioned start for the sake of simplicity. It doesn't work, either if the service is running - giving restart, or if the service is stopped - giving start.

Comment: my bets are still on SSH not finding the configuration that allows it to log in at `someserver` without password when run from crontab :)

Comment: @Krackout then, as ralz says, manually specify which key to use, using `ssh -i /path/to/key someuser@someserver…`

Comment: Run some tests: discover if the problem is with `ssh` or with the other part (strip back the problem to only calling ssh from cron). Then decide what to do next. You can on the server look at the `sshd` logs to see if the connection is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I originally suspected, the problem was `ssh -t`.

The solution, I added this in `/etc/sudoers` on the SSH server side:

```
Defaults:someuser !requiretty
```

I can't tell what is `requiretty` used for. To be on the safe side I disabled it for a user only, not globally. It doesn't seem to affect this user in other aspects.